# Python http.server options

Tags: python-3.x, http.server

Recently I was trying to developing my DownloadManager , cause of that I created test server by this command in Terminal:

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

but when I was trying to take range of a specific file , it always give me whole of file ! , when I try my code on my real WebSite(hosted on my domain), it work true.

should I add another option to **python -m http.server** ?